# Removing git untracked files from status without deleting from HD

Tags: git

I'm new to git and on *"git status"* I find my hard drive content as *"untracked files".
I tried all solutions I found in other posts without being able to solve the problem.

How can I make sure to remove the untracked files from git without deleting them from my hard drive?

Comment: Try putting them in `.gitignore`.  That way git will stop tracking them.

Comment: An untracked file already *isn't* in Git. More precisely, Git's definition of an untracked file is any file present in the work-tree that is not also in Git's *index*. The index is slightly mysterious as there's no direct way to see it, but it's also called the *staging area* and it contains a copy of every file that was committed to `HEAD`, and you `git add <file>` to copy files from your work-tree into your index to update them in order to have the *new* version go into the *next* commit. So if a file *isn't* in the index, it doesn't go into the *next* commit either.

Comment: @Sid: adding a file name to `.gitignore` does not cause Git to stop tracking a file. It only affects files that are already untracked: it tells Git to stop *complaining* that it's untracked, and not to automatically `git add` the file when you say "add everything". (But this just means that adding the name to `.gitignore` is normally the right answer.)

Comment: Ok, problem solved.
Thanks everybody :)
I just added all untracked files to txt file then renamed ".gitignore" and positioned into the root folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try use a .gitignore file on the root of your git project folder.

here's a nice explanation: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

and a collection of commonly useful gitignore files: https://github.com/github/gitignore

Answer (score 1):

create a .gitignore file and add them in it you can learn more [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)